# Difference between system and priv-app in system partition

Tags: android

What is the difference between apps in system partition and apps in system priv-app partition? As tried I am not finding any live scenarios with respect to app permissions. Request anyone to update info's regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

System apps are just apps bundled with the system, which cannot be uninstalled. Nothing more. For instance, the YouTube app can be a system app.

On the other hand, system privileged apps are like system apps, but with superior permissions. For instance, the SystemUI app is privileged (at least on my device it is) because it requires elevated permissions to work.

Comment: SystemUI app means which app basically your referring to

Comment: The SystemUI app is, well... the system ui, like the notifications panel, the lock screen, the settings app...